# Problems with using an external USB harddrive on android

Tags: external-hard-drive, filesystems, android

I have an external USB harddrive, a 1Tb WD Passport (red), and decided to reformat it for use with both my windows PC and my android tablet. There have been some problems along the way that i've overcome for the most part:

- Picked up a USB-microUSB adapter at my local consumer electronics store. I confirmed that it is working as intended, as the tablet sees the drive, but doesn't recognize the filesystem.
- Windows 7 wanted to format it to exFAT or NTFS. Windows 7 can't format disks larger than 32Gb with FAT32(why? It can read it just fine.)

I used a third party tool [made by Ridgecorp Consultants](http://www.ridgecrop.demon.co.uk/index.htm?fat32format.htm) to reformat the disk with FAT32. The drive now works fine with Win7, both reading and writing. Windows also claims that the filesystem is FAT32 (as opposed to exFAT as earlier), so I'll take its word for it.

However, Android still claims that the drive is "Empty or with an unrecognized filesystem". What gives? My research has revealed that this should work.

The tablet is a Samsung Galaxy S with Android 4.4.2.

**UPDATE**

Tested it on my Samsung Galaxy Note 3 phone, and it worked. Also using Android 4.4.2. As the drive is a USB3 device, i'm suspecting that the tablet is unable to output enough current via its micro USB port, as i cannot hear the drive spinning up. I suspect that a powered USB hub, or perhaps those Y-cable with a charger connected could do the trick.

Comment: Questions about Android devices are not on topic.  As for the reason FAT32 is limited to 32GB that's what the specification supports.  Its possible your device does not support external HDDs.  I personally in all my times of working with Android devices never found one that did.  I have only ever used the supported built-in removable flash drive storage media.

Comment: @Ramhound The tablet recognizes it as storage, just having issues with the filesystem, or so it claims. Also, see the update-edit.

Comment: Does not change the fact its still not on topic here.

Comment: The 32 GB limit on FAT32 is artificial. Probably to get people to use ExFAT or whatever. The actual limit is 2 TiB or 16 TiB with 4Kn sectors.

Comment: 1st comment above is not quite right. The Fat32 format has a theoretical limit of 16TB and practical limit around 8TB (I think, maybe Daniel is more correct than I am). Microsoft owns the IP for the exFAT format, and recommends anything over 32GB for obvious reasons. If you want to use Android OTG USB and read write in exFAT you need to pay a licensing fee as a developer. Current ballpark estimate is around $5.00 per device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suspected in the update mentioned in the question, the issue was that the harddrive did not supply enough power, so the disk never spun up properly.

When connecting the drive via a powered USB3 hub, it worked fine, as the USB hub then supplied the power via its USB3 port, instead of relying on the tablet to do this. The tablet can now read the 1TB external drive as if it was a memory card, and since the filesystem is FAT32, it makes it an easy medium for transferring stuff between desktop computer, laptop, phone, and tablet.